# Need explanation of Syntax of CML

Tags: concurrency, sml, ml

Can somebody please explain the syntax of cell data type :

```
datatype 'a request = READ | WRITE of 'a

datatype 'a cell = CELL of {
  reqCh : 'a request chan,
  replyCh : 'a chan
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're confused by, but this should somewhat explain the types.

The datatype `'a cell` has one constructor, `CELL`, whose argument is a record with two fields:
`reqCh`, which is an `'a request chan`, and `replyCh`, which is an `'a chan`.

You don't provide the definition of `chan`, so I can't really clarify that. However, an
`'a request` has two constructors, `READ` and `WRITE`. The former has no argument, while
the second takes an argument of type `'a`.

For example, given some type `t`, a `t request chan` `x`, and an `t chan` `y`, you could have something like:

```
val aCell : t cell = CELL {reqCh = x, replyCh = y}
```

Comment: I could not understand the reqCh : 'a request chan, part. what does it tell about he datatype of reqCh ?

Comment: This means that `reqCh` is a `t chan`, where the type `t` is `s request` for some type `s`. As you haven't defined what a `chan` is, I can't really explain much further. If you want an example of an `s request`, consider `READ`. `READ` is an `s request` for any type `s`. `WRITE 5` is an `int request`. `WRITE "foo"` is a `string request`.

Comment: If i suppose that request is : Write 5. so what does it mean for reqCh to be of type "Write 5 chan" ?

Comment: `request` would not be `WRITE 5`. However, `WRITE 5` is a value of type `int request`. You seem to not have much understanding of how the type system in ML works, and so I suggest that you read [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Standard_ML_Programming/Types) or something with similar information. To find out about what a `chan` type is, try looking at [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15312-f02/handouts/25-cml.pdf). A `t chan` is a type that deals with passing messages of type `t`, so an `s request chan` is a type dealing with passing messages that are of type `s request`.